# number of ways of placing balls on plate

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are `n plates` places in a line and unlimited number of `red balls` with values from `1` to `k` and there are unlimited of black balls.How can I calculate number of ways I can place `n balls in n plates` with following restrictions:

1) Plate number `1` and `n` cannot have a black ball.

2) Plate number `2` to `n-1` should have at-least 1 black ball.

3) `No two adjacent plates` can have black balls.

4) `No two adjacent red balls` can  have a same number.

Comment: And this is not any homework ,I made this up.

Comment: You can easily eliminate condition $2)$ by subtracting out the number of arrangements of only red balls satisfying condition $4)$, which is $k(k-1)^{n-1}$.

Comment: Conditions 2 and 3 seem contradictory?

Comment: @Cocopuffs: How is that?

Comment: @joriki That all plates $2$ to $n-1$ have black balls, but no two adjacent plates have black balls. Probably I don't understand

Comment: @Cocopuffs: Not suprisingly, since the formulation is ungrammatical; but it seems clear that what the OP meant was "$2)$ There should be at least $1$ black ball on the plates with numbers $2$ to $n-1$".

Answer (score 0):

Let's arrange the plates from left to right with increasing numbers, and let's choose numbers for the red balls from left to right. There are $k$ options for the red ball on plate $1$. For every remaining red ball, there are $k-1$ options if it's to the right of a red ball and $k$ options if it's to the right of a black ball. Thus if there are $j$ black balls, there are $k^{j+1}(k-1)^{n-2j-1}$ options for numbering the red balls.

Given $j$ black balls and $n-j-1$ red balls to put on plates $2$ to $n$, where plate $n$ must have a red ball, glue a red ball to the right of every black ball and choose $j$ out of $n-j-1$ slots to place the black/red pairs (with the remaining $n-2j-1$ slots filled with the remaining red balls). Then the total number of arrangements is

$$
\sum_{j=1}^{\lceil n/2\rceil-1}\binom{n-j-1}jk^{j+1}(k-1)^{n-2j-1}\;.
$$